# How to echo href to editable div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am attempting to echo a link into an editable div. This is handled by JQuery and then passed to an html file. 
echo in php script

```
echo "<a href='Olliff_index.html'>Return to Main Menu</a>";
```

Received by

```
var formData = $('#billingForm,#videoForm').serializeArray();
        $.post('Olliff_receipt.php', formData, function(data) {
            $('div#Wrapper').empty().append(data);
        });
```

div#Wrapper references

```
<div id="Wrapper" contenteditable="true">
        <div id="form">
        <h3>Bob's Order Form</h3>
        <p>Please Select a Department</p>
        <br />
        <form id="videoForm">
            <div id="header" contenteditable="true" align="center"></div>
            <div style="height:200px;overflow:auto;" id="department" contenteditable="true"></div>
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset"/>
            <div id="msg" contenteditable="true"></div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The result is the text "Return to Main Menu" and it appears to be a link (underlined blue font) but is not clickable. Some extra info I'm not sure is related is this is all taking place within Olliff_index.html so the href is linking to the file it is in but that shouldn't matter right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your js, try to add this:

```
var formData = $('#billingForm,#videoForm').serializeArray();
    $.post('Olliff_receipt.php', formData, function(data) {
        $('div#Wrapper').empty().append(data);
        $('div#Wrapper').removeAttr('contenteditable'); //new line
    });
```

With this change, your href will be clickable

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why that is an issue? Why would the attribute contenteditable prevent the formation of a link?

Comment: Really i'm not sure the reason, but i think is because with this tag, your document is maybe waiting a edition of this div, and your browser interpret your href still how a simple text and no how a html entity...

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the attribute:

```
contenteditable="true"
```

in the

```
<div id="Wrapper" contenteditable="true">
```